# selecting multiple items in a listbox using htmldocument's SetAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dom

I know that I can select an option in a listbox within my HTMLDocument (which refers to a webbrowser control's HTMLDocument) using SetAttribute. For example:

```
htDoc.GetElementById("lstCountries").SetAttribute("value", "88")
```

However, I can't figure out how I can select multiple items within the listbox. When I call SetAttribute repeatedly, it always unselects the old one first.

Thanks.